# Why do polyoxometalates have good electrochemical/ redox properties?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, coordination-compounds, catalysis

Many authors are using polyoxomethalates immobilised in carbon nanomaterial as electrocatalysts for energy related reactions (ORR, HER, OER). Other metal alloys have also shown to be successful as electrocatalysts for energy related reactions.

I would like to know what makes polyoxometalates have these good redox properties, is it just because the high valency of the metal/addenda atoms that makes the multiple-electron acceptance ?

If it is possible to give an explanation based on coordination chemistry (molecular orbitals), it would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.